# Wigner matrices and Catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, random-matrices, catalan-numbers

I am reading about Wigner matrices right now and have come across the computation for even moments 
$$\frac{2\cdot 2^k}{\pi}\int_{\pi/-2}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2k}x \cos^2x \; dx = C_k$$
where $C_k = \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}.$ 
I've considered a couple cases for different values of $k$ to see if I could conclude how one arrives at the Catalan numbers, but I don't see it.

Can anyone explain how this computation is done?

Comment: The [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Properties) can also be written as the difference between two binomial coefficients. And so can your integral, after writing $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x,~$ and employing [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).